# How to Setup GitLab Environment Variables in a safe way?

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I don't wan't to put sensitive Credentials (Like API keys, passwords etc) into my branch.
For this, GitLab (and other CI/CD-Services) are able to set Environment-Variables. They will be injected into the script during deployment process.

I know about two ways for GitLab to set them:

1. Via UI: `Project` ⇒ `Settings` ⇒ `CI/CD` ⇒ `Variables`
2. Via `.gitlab-ci.yml`

As in my opinion the first way is the secure one, because no files with credentials are saved in the git repo but it's also the more complicated way because I have to set each single variable by hand via GitLab-GUI.

With the second way, the issue is that `.gitlab-ci.yml` is saved into the gitlab repo so that the credentials are not secure.

**Question:**
Is there a way to define the ENV-Vars in a file and provide it to GitLab, without putting them into the branch?
Or is there another way to create those ENV-Vars easily and securely in GitLab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to define the ENV-Vars in a File?

Yes, in UI settings you mentioned you can specify variables type to be `variable` (key:value) or `file` (in Key will be passed path to secret file with content from value input).

So **file variable** seems like what you are looking for.

[Readme](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#variables) and [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables) provide good description for variables. Personally I find very useful other options: variable masking and protected state.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks makozaki, 
that was a good hint, but there are some special requirements:

First go to your Project ⇒ Settings ⇒ CI/CD ⇒ Variables and add them like this: 
[image]

The `Key` will be turned in a File-Name and the values you entered will be as Data inside this File.

In the `Job-Logs` of the CI-Process it provides the full Path to your new generated File... it looks like this: 
`ENV_PRODUCTION: '/builds/yourProjectGroup/gatsby_netlifycms_starter.tmp/ENV_PRODUCTION',`

> **Notice**
>
> you can't choose the easy way and name it `.env.production` to use it
>   with `dotenv`Because the Key-Field don't allow special-characters like `.`,

Now as you got the `File` with all your config-values, you can easily implement it in your Application (e.g. with dotenv).

For my Gatsby implementation it looks like this.

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: process.env.ENV_PRODUCTION ? process.env.ENV_PRODUCTION : `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
const config = require('gatsby-plugin-config').default;
```

What's happening here? The dotenv.config() is checking, if your self-created ENV_PRODUCTION exists... if yes, it will be used. Else it will use the general `.env.<yourNodeEnviroment>` one.

So with the above given Values in `ENV_PRODUCTION`, you are able to access `FIRST_VALUE` within your Application.

This way it's easy to have an `.env.development` for running your application ot local machine, and using `ENV_PRODUCTION` env from Gitlab on production.

Comment: I am using the first method as you explained here. Could you plz tell me, how are you managing the job-logs?? Where do I need to keep these job-logs (yaml file or other place) ?? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I want to clear more, that where to put the key in the YAML file?

Comment: @AJEETSINGH The JobLogs are in CI/CD, if you have something like an deployment process. That are the logs, what exactly Gitlab do while deployment. 
There you can lookout for the name you choosed for your File-Settings (in the above Example: ENV_PRODUCTION).
You don't need a yaml file, if you choose the `Gitlab-"Add-Variable"` Way. It's an alternate way to get own variables into your deployment Process by runtime.
IF you want to use `.gitlab-ci.yml`, place it into the root of your project-repository